# Search a list of Item Lists and return all elements of list with Python

Tags: python, list

I have a large list of lists that looks like this...

[[16W1509462     ,  FR-CHJAV-VSDB4234HL           ,  30.5,  42.0, 0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509463     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HL        ,  30.5,  42.0,  0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509463     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HL        ,  30.5,  42.0, 0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509473     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HR        ,  30.5,  42.0,  0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509473     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HR        ,  30.5,  42.0, 0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509481     ,  FR-CHJAV-VSDB4834HD           ,  30.5,  48.0,  0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509481     ,  FR-CHJAV-VSDB4834HD           ,  30.5,  48.0, 0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509503     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB6034HD        ,  30.5,  60.0,  0.75,  JAVA      ],

[16W1509503     ,  FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB6034HD        ,  30.5,  60.0, 0.75,  JAVA      ]]

I'm developing a program for my company so when an operator scans an item(the first element in the list is the item number), it will show them the description, length, width, thickness, and paint color.

I would like to store the item number they scan in a variable then search for that item in the list of lists then show them the specs of the item such as length, width, thickness so on.

I've checked many other forums and to no avail I have not found anything that seems to do what I need so I'm not sure if this is even possible

Essentially I would like the output to look like this

---

Item scanned: 16W1509462

16W1509462 , FR-CHJAV-VSDB4234HL , 30.5, 42.0, 0.75, JAVA

Comment: The last 2 rows (among others) have the same id `16W1509503`. Is that an error, or are the keys not unique?

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that each value stored in the nested list is a string except for the numbers. Also, I am assuming that there are no duplicate item numbers like in your sample list. Then this should work, if I understood your question properly.

```
item_to_scan = '16W1509462'
for sample in sample_list:
    if sample[0] == item_to_scan:
        print(sample) # or you can do whatever you want to do with the sample
```

Input:

```
sample_list = [
    ['16W1509462', 'FR-CHJAV-VSDB4234HL', 30.5, 42.0, 0.75, 'JAVA'],
    ['16W1509463', 'FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HL', 30.5, 42.0, 0.75, 'JAVA'],
    ['16W1509473', 'FR-CHJAV-BT-VSDB4234HR', 30.5, 42.0, 0.75, 'JAVA'],
]
```

Output:

```
['16W1509462', 'FR-CHJAV-VSDB4234HL', 30.5, 42.0, 0.75, 'JAVA']
```